# How to get R.raw string for random

Tags: android

I have a certain number of file audio in R.raw folder. 
I wish to use them in random.

My code is the following

```
String sounds[]={"file1","file2","file3","file4","file5"};
random=new Random();
int j =16;
int k = random.nextInt(j);

String suoni =sounds[ k];
String media="R.raw."+suoni;
mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(media));
```

It doesn't work. 
Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 5):

Create an array with references to your sound files (those are `int`!). And select an random one:

```
int sounds[] = { R.raw.file1, R.raw.file2, ... };
int k = random.nextInt(sounds.length);
MediaPlayer.create(context, sounds[k]).start();
```